# How to achieve multiple layouts for cards using a single grid or flex?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a responsive card layout as shown in the image.

[image]

Currently what I am doing is that I am separately creating layouts for computers, tablets and mobile. then which the help of a `media query` I set the display property as `display: none` for the other two views.

For example: if I am in computer view the card layout for the computer will not have a display set as none while the other two will have a `display as none`.

This works but is causing a lot of redundancy. There is a way to achieve all three layouts using a flex or grid.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex can achieve this easily.

Depending upon the screen width you can add media queries as following, you can tweak with box width and max-width to resize the boxes.

```
/* tablet view */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .parent-container {
        max-width: 320px;
    }
}


/* mobile view */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .parent-container {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

You can check this out https://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/wbqoLe0y/35/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set the `display: none` everytime you want to design a certain design for a screen size. *Media queries* bring something called a ***breakpoint*** where you can specify the width (like `min-width: 768px`) of your screen. For mobile screen sizes just put your css under the *media query* with `max-width: 600px`. Further you can instead use the `orientation` property to distinguish between *landscape* or *portrait* mode. 
[More on Queries and screen sizes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```css
//for mobile
    @media query and only screen(max-width: 600px) 
    {
        display:flex;
        //some more css-code
    }
    
//for tablet
    @media query and only screen(min-width: 600px) 
   {

    display: flex;
   //some more css-code

   }
   
//for desktop size
   @media query and only screen(min-width: 768px) 
  {
     display: flex;
     //some more css-Code
  }
```

Make sure to follow the mobile first development approach like recommended under 
[MDN Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Responsive/Mobile_first)